# Generating random numbers a, b, c such that a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 1

Tags: python, random

To do some simulations in Python, I'm trying to generate numbers a,b,c such that `a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 1`. I think generating some `a` between 0 and 1, then some `b` between 0 and `sqrt(1 - a^2)`, and then `c` = `sqrt(1 - a^2 - b^2)` would work.

Floating point values are fine, the sum of squares should be *close* to 1. I want to keep generating them for some iterations.

Being new to Python, I'm not really sure how to do this. Negatives are allowed.

Edit: Thanks a lot for the answers!

Comment: With what precision? Randomized? A sequence?

Comment: `c = 1 - a - b` would be wrong, it would be `c = sqrt(1 - a**2 - b**2)`

Comment: @JohanL Totally random. Precision is better if it's higher, but shouldn't affect the speed preferably.

Comment: @CoryKramer Oops, will edit the question.

Comment: try "1^2 + 0^2 + 0^2" or provide context

Comment: "totally random" is ambiguous in this context. You will get different probability densities based on what variable you choose to be random. One possibility for what I think you might be after, is to take random numbers `a`,`b`,`c` and then divide each of them by `sqrt(a**2 + b**2 + c**2)`.

Comment: @VBB I think relative to the answers given so far, yours could be less biased? Since a, b and c are chosen independently of each other?

Comment: Could the individual `a`, `b` and `c` be negative? That is not quite clear from the question.

Comment: @JohanL Negative numbers are fine too. Sorry for not mentioning it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "right" answer depends on whether you are looking for a uniform random distribution in space, or on the surface of a sphere, or something else. If you are looking for points on the surface of a sphere, you still have to worry about the `cos(theta)` factor which will cause points to appear "bunched up" near the poles of the sphere. Since exact nature is not clear from your question, here is a "totally random" distribution that should work:

```
x = np.random.uniform(0,1,3) # random numbers in [0, 1)
x /= np.sqrt(x[0] ** 2 + x[1] ** 2 + x[2] ** 2)
```

Another advantage here is that since we are using numpy arrays, you can quickly scale to large sets of points too, by using `x = np.random.uniform(0, 1, (3, n))` for any `n`.

Comment: in case you're dealing with uniform distributions between 0 and 1 you could also use `np.random.random`.

Comment: This will not allow the individual elements to be negative, as specified that they could, in the comments.

Comment: @JohanL a, b, c can be randomly multiplied by +/-1 If I'm not wrong

Comment: @four_lines True, then it is only a matter of what "totally random" means. This obviously fulfills the requirements, but according to the link provided in my answer, the resulting values won't be uniformly distributed on a sphere.

Comment: You can also use `np.random.uniform(-1, 1, 3)` to get random numbers between [-1, 1)

Answer (score 8):

According to [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7977/how-to-generate-uniformly-distributed-points-on-the-surface-of-the-3-d-unit-sphe) answer at stats.stackexchange.com, you should use normally distributed values to get uniformly distributed values on a sphere. That would mean, you could do:

```
import numpy as np
abc = np.random.normal(size=3)
a,b,c = abc/np.sqrt(sum(abc**2))
```

Comment: Take absolute value of the numerator to get uniform(0,1) rather than uniform(-1,1).

Comment: @pjs Yes, but according to the clarifications in the comments to the question, the OP was OK with negative and positive values for the variables.

Comment: Ah, that was in the "hidden" comments.

Answer (score 8):

Just in case your interested in the probability densities I decided to do a comparison between the different approaches:

```
import numpy as np
import random
import math

def MSeifert():
    a = 1
    b = 1
    while a**2 + b**2 > 1:  # discard any a and b whose sum of squares already exceeds 1
        a = random.random()
        b = random.random()
    c = math.sqrt(1 - a**2 - b**2)  # fixed c
    return a, b, c

def VBB():
    x = np.random.uniform(0,1,3) # random numbers in [0, 1)
    x /= np.sqrt(x[0] ** 2 + x[1] ** 2 + x[2] ** 2)
    return x[0], x[1], x[2]

def user3684792():
    theta = random.uniform(0, 0.5*np.pi)
    phi = random.uniform(0, 0.5*np.pi)
    return np.sin(theta)* np.cos(phi), np.sin(theta)*np.sin(phi), np.cos(theta)

def JohanL():
    abc = np.random.normal(size=3)
    a,b,c = abc/np.sqrt(sum(abc**2))
    return a, b, c

def SeverinPappadeux():
    cos_th = 2.0*random.uniform(0, 1.0) - 1.0
    sin_th = math.sqrt(1.0 - cos_th*cos_th)
    phi = random.uniform(0, 2.0*math.pi)
    return sin_th * math.cos(phi), sin_th * math.sin(phi), cos_th
```

And plotting the distributions:

```
%matplotlib notebook

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f, axes = plt.subplots(3, 4)

for func_idx, func in enumerate([MSeifert, JohanL, user3684792, VBB]):
    axes[0, func_idx].set_title(str(func.__name__))
    res = [func() for _ in range(50000)]
    for idx in range(3):
        axes[idx, func_idx].hist([i[idx] for i in res], bins='auto')

axes[0, 0].set_ylabel('a')
axes[1, 0].set_ylabel('b')
axes[2, 0].set_ylabel('c')

plt.tight_layout()
```

With the result:

[image]

Explanation: The rows show the distributions for `a`, `b` and `c` respectively while the columns show the histograms (distributions) of the different approaches.

The only approaches that give a uniformly random distribution in the range `(-1, 1)` are JohanLs and Severin Pappadeux's approach. All other approaches have some features like spikes or a functional behavior in the range `[0, 1)`. Note that these two solution currently gives values between -1 and 1 while all other approaches give values between 0 and 1.

Comment: Nice plots. It's worth pointing out that the fact that a uniform distribution on the sphere gives uniform marginal distributions is rather subtle, and is special to the 2-sphere: the corresponding result doesn't apply to a circle or a hypersphere.

Comment: Cool analysis :)

Answer (score 6):

I think it is actually a cool problem, and a nice way to do this is to just use spherical polar coordinates and generate the angles at random.

```
import random
import numpy as np
def random_pt():
    theta = random.uniform(0, 0.5*np.pi)
    phi = random.uniform(0, 0.5*np.pi)
    return np.sin(theta)* np.cos(phi), np.sin(theta)*np.sin(phi), np.cos(theta)
```

Comment: This should be the right solution, basically you select a random point on the surface of a unit sphere. Wonder why the question has been downvoted.

Comment: That's a really clever way but it doesn't seem to work currently: The sum of squares won't always add up to one and it can return a negative value but the question stated they should be in [0, 1].

Comment: Aah, I didn't think of that. But that can be resolved by constraining theta and phi in range `[0 pi/2]`. Why don't you edit the answer?

Comment: ah, yes you can constrain the quadrant

Comment: still won't add up to one (not even close) in most cases. Are you sure you have the correct trigonometric functions there?

Comment: The distributions don't appear the same for this one either. Did you try plotting the histogram?

Comment: lol, fixed the other bug. It should have been cos theta at the end not cos phi

Comment: @user3684792 Sorry, I may have overridden your changes. I figured you swapped theta and phi and I used `math` because it's (much) faster for scalars. I rolled it back already (because I didn't see your last change that limited the range of the uniform distribution) but you might want to take a look at it. :)

Comment: wow, i didn't know that about math. I trust numpy too much maybe

Comment: Well, if you use `np.random.uniform(0, np.pi/2, size=10000)` for `theta` and `phi` you can easily (and efficiently) create large arrays of random values. But if you only use scalars the numpy functions `np.sin` and `np.cos` will be much slower than the `math` functions.

Answer (score 4):

You could do it like this:

```
import random
import math

def three_random_numbers_adding_to_one():
    a = 1
    b = 1
    while a**2 + b**2 > 1:  # discard any a and b whose sum of squares already exceeds 1
        a = random.random()
        b = random.random()
    c = math.sqrt(1 - a**2 - b**2)  # fixed c
    return a, b, c

a, b, c = three_random_numbers_adding_to_one()
print(a**2 + b**2 + c**2)
```

However `float`s have only limited precision so these won't add to exactly `1`, just approximately.

You may need to check if the numbers generated with this function are "random enough". It could be that this setup biases the "randomness".

Comment: the trouble with this is that the distributions of the 3 coordinates are different, specifically E(c) > E(a), E(b)

Comment: It might be nitpicking but equal distribution wasn't mentioned in the question and note that I added a comment about that at the end already. :)

Answer (score 3):

Time to add another solution, heh...

This time it is truly uniform on the unit sphere point picking - check http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html for details

```
import math
import random

def random_pt():
    cos_th = 2.0*random.uniform(0, 1.0) - 1.0
    sin_th = math.sqrt(1.0 - cos_th*cos_th)
    phi = random.uniform(0, 2.0*math.pi)
    return sin_th * math.cos(phi), sin_th * math.sin(phi), cos_th

for k in range(0, 100):
    a, b, c = random_pt()

    print("{0} {1} {2} {3}".format(a, b, c, a*a + b*b + c*c))
```